# Reset and loop jquery animation

Tags: jquery, animation, loops

I am animating some HTML objects to look like snowflakes falling but am having some trouble on the loop.

Here is my code:

```
//animation function
function snowflakeAnimate(index) {
    //random numbers
    //time
    var nTime = randomRange(9000,35000);
    var randTime = Math.round(nTime);

    //delay
    var nDelay = randomRange(200,35000);
    var randDelay = Math.round(nDelay);

    $(this).delay(randDelay).animate({
        marginTop: "+600px"
    }, randTime);
};

$(".tweet").each(snowflakeAnimate);
```

So all it is doing at the moment is animating a snowflake by increasing the top margin to 600. The delay and animation speed are set by generating a random number. My question is how do I reset the snowflake to the top and then run the animation again so it never stops falling.

Comment: are you trying to do something like: http://www.somethinghitme.com/2010/04/29/jquery-snowfall-plugin-1-3/?

Comment: @BookOfZeus yeah whoever wrote that plugin is friggin AMAZING! :P

Answer (score 0):

I think [The jQuery animate() step callback function](http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/03/01/the-jquery-animate-step-callback-function/) is your friend here.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I couldn't get it looping...just resetting. What I've done for the time being is install the [Jquery Timers plugin](http://jquery.offput.ca/js/jquery.timers.js), did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it - just had to get the syntax right for the function calling itself...

```
    function snowflakeAnimate(sfAnimate) {

        //Animation
        $(sfAnimate).addClass("moving").delay(randDelay).animate({
            marginTop: 600
        }, 20000, function() {
            $(sfAnimate).animate({
                marginTop: -150
            }, 0, function() {
                snowflakeAnimate(sfAnimate);
            });
        });
}
```

So there it is...an infinite loop animation. If you want to see it in action you can check it out at [traxmas.realadventure.co.uk](http://traxmas.realadventure.co.uk)