# Running and resetting an animation each time a seperate animation reaches a position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, reset

(This seems like it should be rather basic but I'm not sure how to handle it this.)

In a nutshell, whenever *img* (one of the FB logos) is -20 or farther, I would like the "dust" animation to occur, to create the effect that whenever the logo hits the footer a cloud of dust is kicked up.

I can easily get the animation to occur once, but need help getting it to occur multiple times. (Would collision detection be recommended for this? I assume I'd also need to reset the position and opacity, also. Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270574/reset-and-loop-jquery-animation) fit in somehow?)

*Here's a gif of the basic idea:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3HQP.gif

*Here's a fiddle of what currently happens:* http://jsfiddle.net/x6dferhh/4/

```
step: function(img, tween) {

                if (img > -20 ) {
                    $("#"+ link.data("dust")).attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/oTZ9G9Z.png');
                    $("#"+ link.data("dust")).animate({
                        top: '-150',
                        opacity: '0'
                    }, 500);
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add a callback that executes when the "dust" animation completes.

```
function settleDust () {
  // reset the animation for next time
}

$("#"+ link.data("dust")).animate({
  top: '-150',
  opacity: '0'
}, 500, settleDust);
```

See the jQuery.animate docs: 
http://api.jquery.com/animate/#basic-usage

Comment: Would putting the function past the duration also be considered the callback function? Like `}, 500, function() { console.log("d");}` For some reason `complete` doesn't recognize anything I put in, but the function after the duration does. (Strange)

Comment: @Terf according to the docs it looks like that should work as well. I'll update my answer

Comment: I think I figured out what I wanted to do below. (I can't mark it as the answer until tomorrow, however.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all I had to do was reset the CSS to essentially get what I wanted.

```
if (now > -5) {
    $("#"+ link.data("dust")).css('top', '0');
    $("#"+ link.data("dust")).css('opacity', '1');
    $("#"+ link.data("dust")).animate({
        top: '-50px',
        opacity: '0',
    }, randomTime/5);
}
```